# Script running on OSX but failing on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

In my `package.json` I have the following script:

```
"scripts": {
    "run-trader": "app='member' webpack-dev-server --config ./config/webpack.dev.js "
}
```

What I achieved with this was that the `app` variable was passed down as an environment variable to the `webpack` file, so then inside the file I could do

```
var app = process.env.app
```

and get the value `member`.

Now this doesn't seem to work on windows using the same `node` and `npm` version as OSX.

The error that I get is the following:

```
> app='member' webpack-dev-server --config ./config/webpack.dev.js 

npm : 'app' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
At line:1 char:1
+ npm run-script run-member
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('app' is not re...ternal command,:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? It looks like it is trying to run a script called `app`.

**Note:** I have other scripts very similar to this one and they all work on OSX but they don't on windows; the difference is the appname.

Comment: thanks @zero298 I was looking for that and I couldn't get to that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) this lib would help you.

Change your script:

```
cross-env app=member webpack-dev-server --config ./config/webpack.dev.js
```

It should work.